# How can I check which app is using my microphone on Android

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am wondering is there a way that I can know which app is occupying the microphone? Since the microphone can be used by only one app each time.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is a design principle of android that your app will never know the name/ id of another app/ process requesting a resource your app is trying to request as well. Having said that, MediaRecorder seems to be much more robust than for example MediaPlayer, just check [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html)